# Empty project properties in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 stopped showing project properties properly.

It's empty in both the Application and Compilation sections:

[image]

[image]

As such, I can't change the application icon or the project type, neither add .xml documentation.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do all project types exhibit this behavior?  Have you tried repairing your VS installation?

Comment: click o the yellow icon and do the pending VS update and look if this fixes it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That fixed it. Thank you.